# Effective solution to map names with groups

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some staff names. Each staff can be in different groups. Say staff names are N1, N2, and N3, and group names are G1, and G2.

I need to show in a webpage which staff belongs which group (sorting by groups). E.g. G1 contains N1 and N2.

Also I need to show (when another button is clicked) for each staff what are the groups they belongs to. E.g. N1 belongs to G1 and G2.

What is the effective way to do this in a webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have create an object with staffname as key and groupsArray as value;

Others must be self-explanatory; Hope this helps

```js
let staffsArray = ["N1","N2","N3"];

staffs = [{
 "N1" : ["G1","G2","G3"]
},{
 "N2" : ["G1"]
},
{
 "N3" : ["G3"]
},
{
 "N4" : ["G2","G3"]
}]

window.onload =  appendStaffsToDropDown();

function appendStaffsToDropDown() {
 staffsArray.map((staffName) => {
  let staffNameDiv = document.createElement("option"); 
  let x = document.createElement("OPTION");
     x.setAttribute("value", staffName);
     let t = document.createTextNode(staffName);
     x.appendChild(t);
     document.getElementById("staffDropDown").appendChild(x)
 });
 displayStaffDetails();
}


function displayStaffDetails() {
 staffsArray.map((staffName) => {
  staffs.map((staffObject) => {
   if(staffObject[staffName] != undefined) {
    let parentDiv = document.getElementById('staffDetails');

    let staffNameDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
    let staffNameContent = document.createTextNode("staffName :" + staffName); 
    staffNameDiv.appendChild(staffNameContent);
    parentDiv.appendChild(staffNameDiv)
    
    let staffGroupDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
    let staffGroupContent = document.createTextNode("StaffGroup :" + staffObject[staffName]); 
    staffGroupDiv.appendChild(staffGroupContent);
    
    parentDiv.appendChild(staffGroupDiv)
   }  
  }); 
 }); 
}


document.getElementById("staffDropDown").onchange = function () {
 let staffName = document.getElementById("staffDropDown").value;

 var filteredDetails = document.getElementById("filteredDetails");
 while (filteredDetails.firstChild) {
     filteredDetails.removeChild(filteredDetails.firstChild);
 }

 staffs.map((staffObject) => {    
  if(staffObject[staffName] != undefined) {
   let parentDiv = document.getElementById('filteredDetails');

   let staffNameDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
   let staffNameContent = document.createTextNode("staffName :" + staffName); 
   staffNameDiv.appendChild(staffNameContent);
   parentDiv.appendChild(staffNameDiv)
   
   let staffGroupDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
   let staffGroupContent = document.createTextNode("StaffGroup :" + staffObject[staffName]); 
   staffGroupDiv.appendChild(staffGroupContent);
   
   parentDiv.appendChild(staffGroupDiv)

   document.getElementById("staffDetails").style.display = 'none';
  }  
 });
}
```

```html
<div id="staffDetails">
</div>

<select id="staffDropDown">
<option>Select Staffs</option>
</select>

<button>
Filter groups
</button>

<div id="filteredDetails">
</div>
```